# My sqlite database is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I create a SQLite database like this:

```
touch database/testing.sqlite
```

and changed my .env for this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database/testing.sqlite
```

When I run migrations and db:seed, everything works. but when I visit the URL I see this error:

```
Database (database/testing.sqlite) does not exist. (SQL: select * from "posts")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `base_path` helper in your database config file to generate a fully qualified path. This will solve the issue without any hard-coding.

In `\config\database.php`

```
'database' => base_path( env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')) ),
```

See [https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-base-path](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#paths)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to set a different path for the sqlite file try to put the absolute path. For example, if I locate my sqlite file in `database/testing/database.sqlite`, I'd do something like this (I'm using Windows btw):

```
# .env
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE='C:/repositories/my-app/database/testing/database.sqlite'
```

You can check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#configuration) of the docs:

> #### SQLite Configuration
>
> After creating a new SQLite database using a command such as `touch database/database.sqlite`, you can easily configure your environment
> variables to point to this newly created database by using the
> database's **absolute path**:
>
> ```
> DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
> DB_DATABASE=/absolute/path/to/database.sqlite
> ```

Comment: is there a way to have this working without the absolute path?Mine is  working with this:
DB_DATABASE=/Users/user/desktop/projects/sovtechBlog/database/testing.sqlite
But I was hoping I could use the relative path

Comment: At least according to the docs, no. I'll update my answer providing that piece of info.